# How to add some value in the specific range in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

How to add the value in specific range in a matrix?

I mean if i have a matrix

Columns 1 through 7

```
 4     4     4     4     4     4     4
48    48    48    48    48    48    48
```

Columns 8 through 14

```
 4     4     4    13    13    13    13
48    48    48    57    57    57    57
```

Columns 15 through 20

```
13    13    13    13    13    13
57    57    57    57    57    57
```

I want to sum all 4 values ,all 13 values,all 48 values,and all 57 values,so the result should be m=[40 130 480 570]

The easiest but stupid method is like this

```
a=sum(1,(1:10));

b=sum(1,(11:20));

c=sum(2,(1:10));

d=sum(2,(11:20));

m=[a b c d]
```

If i want to write a code with for-loop or while-loop to show the result i  want.how do i write the code?

Or can i use the some method to write a code without loop to show this?

Answer (score 4):

Though the solution of @phnx works fine, you can also use the other outputs of the `unique` function in combination with `accumarray` as described in the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#btb0_85):

```
[C, ~, ic] = unique(a);
a_counts = accumarray(ic,1);
m = C.*a_counts
```

This will avoid the warning `'hist' is not recommended...`

Answer (score 3):

A simple two-line solution, with `A` as your original matrix, would be:

```
[a,b]=hist(A(:),unique(A(:)))
c = a .* b'
```

with `a` containing the number of occurances, `b` the unique elements and `c` the sums.